# I don't understand how works injection dependency. Is there somebody which can explain me clearly

Tags: typescript, nestjs, code-injection

I try to realize a little NestJS application in which I want to integrate a task scheduler. One of the first tasks of this scheduler will be to update data in database. This task service will user a UserService like below :

```
import {
  Injectable,
  Inject,
  UnprocessableEntityException,
  HttpStatus,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import { User, UserStatus } from './user.entity';
import { LoggerService } from '../../../logger/logger.service';
import { HammerErrors } from 'src/error/hammer.errors';
import * as Config from '../../../config/global.env';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  private readonly _logger = new LoggerService(UserService.name);

  constructor(
    @Inject('USER_REPOSITORY')
    private _userRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}
  ....
  async reactiveBlockedUsers() {
    this._logger.setMethod(this.reactiveBlockedUsers.name);
    this._logger.log(`Update blocked users`);
    await this._userRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('hm_users')
      .update(User)
      .set({
        nextValidDate: null,
      })
      .where(
        `hm_users.nextValidDate IS NOT NULL hm_users.nextValidDate < utc_timestamp()`,
      )
      .execute();
    return null;
  }
```

}

My task service is as follows:

```
import { LoggerService } from '../../../logger/logger.service';
import { UserService } from '../../providers/user/user.service';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Cron, CronExpression } from '@nestjs/schedule';

@Injectable()
export class TasksService {
  private _logger = new LoggerService(TasksService.name);

  constructor(private _userService: UserService) {}

  @Cron(CronExpression.EVERY_MINUTE)
  async reactiveUsers() {
    this._logger.setMethod(this.reactiveUsers.name);
    this._logger.log(`Reactive blocked users`);
    try {
      await this._userService.reactiveBlockedUsers();
    } catch (error) {
      this._logger.log(error);
    }
  }

  @Cron(CronExpression.EVERY_MINUTE)
  startBatchJobs() {
    this._logger.setMethod(this.startBatchJobs.name);
    this._logger.log(`Start batch job service`);
  }

  triggerNotifications() {}
}
```

The task module is the following :

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TasksService } from './tasks.service';
import { UserService } from 'src/shared/providers/user/user.service';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';

@Module({
  providers: [
    TasksService,
    UserService,
    {
      provide: 'USER_REPOSITORY',
      useClass: Repository,
    },
  ],
})
export class TasksModule {}
```

When I the process works, I have the following trap :
[INFO] 06/05/2020 19:57:00.024 [TasksService.reactiveUsers] TypeError: Cannot read property 'createQueryBuilder' of undefined

Or :
(node:13668) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'createQueryBuilder' of undefined
    at Repository.createQueryBuilder (D:\dev\hammer\hammer-server\node_modules\typeorm\repository\Repository.js:17:29)
    at UserService.reactiveBlockedUsers (D:\dev\hammer\hammer-server\dist\src\shared\providers\user\user.service.js:183:14)
    at TasksService.reactiveUsers (D:\dev\hammer\hammer-server\dist\src\shared\services\tasks\tasks.service.js:25:33)
    at CronJob.fireOnTick (D:\dev\hammer\hammer-server\node_modules\cron\lib\cron.js:562:23)
    at Timeout.callbackWrapper [as _onTimeout] (D:\dev\hammer\hammer-server\node_modules\cron\lib\cron.js:629:10)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
(node:13668) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:13668) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

when I suppress the try catch.

For me it is a problem  of providing Repositiry module which is injected in UserService but I don't understand how that works and how to solve this problem.

If somebody has an idea, I will be interested.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your title sounds like an exact duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection , but your question itself seems to be about a specific error in your specific code. Your question would be more likely to get an answer if the title was more specific to your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

`Repository` is an abstract class in TypeORM and cannot be instantiated directly. Nest does what it can around this, but ultimately it will provide an `undefined` and thus, calling `createQueryBuilder` will give you a problem. As you are using TypeORM, is there a reason you aren't using the `@nestjs/typeorm` package? It manages creating the repository classes for you and makes things much easier. You are are gungho about not using the package, you can always create your own Repository class `UserRepository extends Repository` decorated with the proper metadata and all, and then use that class instead of `Repository`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for information I did not know about this existing package. I will try to implement your proposal. I am a novice in these technology and I discover day by day something new. From beginning of March I have learned HTML, CSS, Javascript, Typescript NestJs and Angular and now I try to implement a little project with all these technologies. I think that I have many hole in my knowledge and I apreciate your answer to give me those informations.

Comment: You can check this part of the docs https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#typeorm-integration